# Register user logout time when closing the application (i.e. all opened windows)

Tags: jsf, monitoring, cdi, logout

I need to register the time that a user logout from my JEE web application, either manually using logout button, or by closing all windows (browsers) opened by the user.

The login/logout is managed using a CDI session bean.

this is what I tried till now:

1. Using of javascript "beforeUnloadEvent" where I call an ajax  request (a servlet inside my application) to register user logout, but this event is fired on each tab/browser closed. Which is not suitable in my case.

```js
     $(window).on('beforeUnloadEvent', function() {
        $.ajax({
           url: '/registerlogout',
           type: 'POST'
          });
        });
```

2. I also tried to perform the registration on "@PreDestroy" method in my bean LoginController, but the method is not called until the "session-timeout" defined in web.xml expires. Whereas the user could have been logged out long time ago.

```
    @Named
    @SessionScoped
    public class LoginController implements Serializable{
       public void login(){
          ...
          saveUserLoginTime();
          ...
       } 
       public void logout(){
          ...
          saveUserLogoutTime();
          ...
       }
       @Predestroy
       public void onclose(){
         saveUserLogoutTime();
       }
    }
```

3. I created a web socket in the template.js and tried to benefit from its "onclose" event, but this also works on each tab closing.

```js
function createWebSocket() {
  var socket = new WebSocket('wss://your-websocket-url');
  
  socket.onopen = function() {
    console.log('WebSocket connection established.');
    // Perform any necessary actions when the connection is opened
  };
  
  socket.onclose = function(event) {
    console.log('WebSocket connection closed with code: ' + event.code);
    handleWebSocketClose();
  };
 
}

function handleWebSocketClose() {
  //ajax call to register userlogouttime
}

createWebSocket();
```

4. I defined a @WebListener that implements HttpSessionListener, but this listener is for all the application, and I can't distinguish the LoginController from others.

```
@WebListener
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener{
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent e){
     ...
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionClosed(HttpSessionEvent e){
     System.out.println("Session close: " + e.getSession().getId());
    }
}
```

AND doing "debug" the session is not destroyed on browser close!

I think that the solution might be in some kind of catching session end or invalidate event or kind of. Such an event that is similar to session destroyed that is fired with HttpSessionListener.I am out of ideas, hope you can help out.

**EDIT:More explanation of the problem**

I am perfectly capable of registring the user logout time when he presses the "logout" button.

The problem is if he closes the browser, the session bean stays alive, and the *PREDESTROY* method is not called.. Apparently this is a bug, or a predefined implementation in CDI. So is the "HttpSession" it even not marked as invalidated... It still alive until the timeout expires..

That's why I was trying other approaches, to try to catch the event of browser closing, because if all windows were closed, and the user reopens the browser, he will be asked to login...

Using websocket didn't help, because, a socket is opened on each tab open or reload, and closed on each tab close or reload... And even if all sockets were closed (tabs), but other project tabs were open, the user session still alive, so if he reopens the project, he will not be asked to login again

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: > Apparently this is a bug, or a predefined implementation in CDI

No that is not a bug. That is how a session is _supposed_ to work.

Comment: Then there is no way to achieve my needs I think?

Answer (score 0):

If this were given to me, here's how I would solve it.

First requirement: If the user's session times out, record the time in which this happens. I would solve this exactly like you did, with a `HttpSessionListener`. Note that, at least in Tomcat, session timeout is exact down to the millisecond. Not sure if that matters to your use case.

The second requirement: If all windows are closed, note their logout time. If you are supposed to end their session when all windows are closed, I think the best way to do this is to have an open websocket on every page. As long as there is at least one open websocket per session, don't end the session. If all websockets are closed, end their session, and then your existing `HttpSessionListener` will fire. You'll have to give some sort of time delay for this however, because websockets close between page loads.

Here's an example of how to use the Java EE websocket api:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-websockets

I would recommend the Javascript approach as it can be easily defeated by the user if they disable Javascript.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your answer. But how can I know that there is at least one open websocket per session? Is there a js method? Or something that I can use in the listener? Note that I did use a websocket, but since it ends with each page it didn't help...

Comment: In your ServerEndpoint, you would keep a map of session ids and websocket sessions. Have a counter for each session.

Comment: I tried your solution, I edited my question for more explanation on why this isn't working.